# post on tumblr after acquiring oAuth tokens

Tags: php, tumblr

I have managed to acquire `oAuth` tokens (`request_token`, `request_token_secret`) from [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tumblr-api/g6SeIBWvsnE) but I cant seem to post to user account with them. 
I would imagine that i would have to first read from the user and get their blog name but i cant find any documentaion about this. 
Can anyone lend a hand on what to do with the tokens please, thank you.

Comment: I really need to get my code cleaned up and put up somewhere for viewing, but I started with [Tumblr OAuth](https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth) by Jacob Budin when building [Followr](http://krisallengallery.com/followr) which I had to fix to work with V2 of the Tumblr API. Followr currently isn't working and hasn't been since the Tumblr outage 2 days ago. I haven't had a chance to even test for the problem so I have no idea what it could be, but Followr used to let you maintain your Follow list with mass updates.

Comment: I see. My Consumer Key and Secret stopped working so I just got another pair. Noting in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: @Ally are you sharing `Followr`?

Comment: I'm going to, but the code is messy, right now. I'd like to get it to where I can release a working Tumblr OAuth tool. Right now, all it's setup to do is to get Profile data for a token, get Followers & Following, and update Following. However, Tumblr has flat out told me they aren't allowing use of Followr anymore because they don't want people mass following and unfollowing people.

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring the tokens will give you authentication but not authorization, you still need to authorize your application against the target Tumblr account. Check the OAuth workflow here:
http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-ii-protocol-workflow/

Comment: thank you,  the process i have includes my `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` which are part of the oAuth sign in.

Comment: I can't access your example link, but have you tried something really simple, like scribe-php? https://github.com/gmaurol/scribe-php

Comment: scribe doesnt seem to support tumblr

Comment: It should be fairly simple to create your own API class, just use the existing ones as reference. Here's an example in Java: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/TumblrApi.java